# Most "sexy" way to display the "impact" of multiple features on a target class?

Tags: data-visualization, multivariate-analysis

Let's say. I have multiple features that take values between (-2 and 2).

**Features** are: "did some sport today", "did some yoga today", "took a cold shower" (for instance if you just did a bit a sport you can evaluate it as 0).

Now, we have a **target** class "I am happy" (red: not happy, grey: neutral, red: happy).

The only way I thought about for graphically representing this is:

[image]

But, since it's a 2-dimentional graph, it's not possible to draw a dot for which all features are at 2.
Actually, it could be possible to represent this with a 3D chart, but what if I use more than 3 features ? 4 ? 5 ? etc.

So, is there any 2D type of graphic where we can see all these information (i.e. the correlations between the multiple features and the class) at once?

**[EDIT]** since it is suggested as an answer, here is a scatter plot matrix of features (sepal length, width etc.) vs flower species (in green, blue and green).

[image]

But I don't understand why are there 3 plots for Sepal.length Vs flower species for instance (same for other features vs flower species)

Comment: Have you considered a scatterplot matrix?

Comment: @whuber hello, thanks for your answer, I have updated my post in order to try to understand if scatterplot matrix is a good fit

Comment: In the iris data example, species is not an axis on any graph, but shown by groups of points with different colours. So nothing is plotted versus species, where versus implies that what follows is on an axis. Three species groups are shown in red, green and blue. Using red and green on the same graph is a bad idea as many people can't tell the difference.

Comment: well we all have our own definition of what "versus" is I guess ;) ,  anyway I think I have found smth closer to my search: Bubble charts. But I am still open to new suggestions

Comment: Bubble charts are not great at displaying "correlations" and aren't going to be terribly effective with more than three variables, anyway.  If they really do meet your needs, then perhaps you haven't expressed them sufficiently clearly.

Comment: @whuber each bubble = a feature, the bigger the bubble the more it has impact on the target class.. no ? But as I said, I am still open to other suggestions

Comment: Visualising ~5 dimensions is about the limit; above that you either need to select a subset of dimensions to look at or use dimension reduction techniques like PCA.

Comment: you may be interested in the *biplot*

Comment: @JohnMadden It looks promising indeed, thanks